Temporarily wrong Android Rotation
I have an activity that starts on landscape mode. When the app starts with the mobile vertically positioned it shows the layout correctly, but when I rotate the device horizontally the layout goes on portrait mode for a brief second and then turns back to the correct landscape mode. Did anyone go through this and knows how to stop it?
App starts in landscape mode:

I click this button, it briefly turns to portrait mode:

Then it goes back to the right landscap mode: 


Android OS takes a little time to switch from landscape to portrait mode ( and vice versa ).
    <activity android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:exported="false"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

You need to add this to your manifest to specify which direction your application should take.
android:screenOrientation="portrait"  if you want the display device to be vertical.
android:screenOrientation="lanscape"  if you want the display device to be horizontal.
